# Como eliminar el main en git?

Tags: git

quiero eliminar la rama Main en git para que ya no quiero seguir trabajando con git, pero el problemas es que esta en un directorio principal(/c/Users/jose Erasmo) y no logro como quitarlo, como lo haria ?, soy nuevo en esto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Solo elimina la carpeta .git que está oculta para dejar de llevar git en ese proyecto, te dejará los últimos cambios, también puedes desinstalar git.

Comment: Si funcionó, gracias

Comment: Confirmo la respuesta de MR Dev y agrego:
Si tenés más de una carpeta .git, vas eliminando de a una a la papelera. Por cada carpeta que elimines, en el git bash hacés un git status. SI continuás teniendo la lista roja de untracked, restaurás esa .git (no es la culpable). Con ese método encontrarás la .git que debés eliminar (cuando hagas git status ya no te mostrará ningún directorio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo elimina la carpeta .git que está oculta para dejar de llevar git en ese proyecto, te dejará los últimos cambios, también puedes desinstalar git.